# "not found: value context" on context.actorSelection where Akka.system.actorFor works in play

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

Using playframwork 2.2.2 (scala). (Upgraded and came from 2.1 I think.)

In an Object I have the following line of code (compiles):

```
val q = Akka.system.actorFor( "akka://application/user/q" )
```

Which is deprecated in this new version. I found [this Akka migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html#use-actorselection-instead-of-actorfor) and changed the line to (does no longer compile):

```
val q = context.actorSelection( "/application/user/q" )
```

But now I'm stuck with this error:

```
not found: value context
```

I have no idea what to do. Google isn't helpful. I have some basic understanding of execution contexts and reckon the problem lies within not having one in the `implicit` scope. Tips, hints, nudges, directions, solutions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ActorSystem`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorSystem) is still an instance of [`ActorRefFactory`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.ActorRefFactory), this in turn defines `actorSelection`. **Since the Play-provided [`Akka.system` is an instance of `ActorSystem`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka), you should be able to simply call:**

```
Akka.system.actorSelection( "/application/user/q")
```

**instead.**

In Akka, the `context` value is available from within the Actor - it is an instance of [`ActorContext`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorContext). That, in turn, subclasses `ActorRefFactory` as well, that's why it *also* provides `actorSelection`.

But that's irrelevant to your case: in Akka 2.2, you should still use an `ActorSystem` instance for "global" selections and other operations.

Comment: This should say `actorSelection`, not `actionSelection`.

Comment: @Ryan: a typo there, thanks for pointing it out. In the future, you can use the "edit" link to suggest the correction directly.

Comment: I tried editing but since it was less than six characters different, SO wouldn't let me save the change.

Comment: @Ryan : arghh, sorry, it's the second time in a row I've forgotten about that limit.